# New Tag Request: hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

Tags: feature-request, tags

Tags exist already for the other fabric SDKs (hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js).

Probably the Java SDK is so new it doesn't yet have a tag.  I think we should fix that, but I don't have enough rep.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java

It would apply nicely to my recent question here :) 
[Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK Use GRPCS for peer and orderer connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625506/hyperledger-fabric-java-sdk-use-grpcs-for-peer-and-orderer-connections)